# formatted response for find query mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have record:

```
{
  "name" : "user",
  "number":"09xxxxxxx21",
  "pc" : [{
      "pcId" : "1",
      "pcName" : "Lenovo",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using" : true
    }, {
      "pcId" : "2",
      "pcName" : "Lenovo",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using": false
    }, {
      "pcId" : "3",
      "pcName" : "Dell",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using": true
    }, {
      "pcId" : "4",
      "pcName" : "Dell",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using": true
    }
  ]}
}
```

using query `.find({'pcID':'4','pc.pcName':'Dell'})` I'm getting complete record but I want record where I have `pcName:'Dell'` only.

Something Like:

```
{
  "name" : "user",
  "number":"09xxxxxxx21",
  "pc" : [
    {
      "pcId" : "3",
      "pcName" : "Dell",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using": true
    }, 
    {
      "pcId" : "4",
      "pcName" : "Dell",
      "pcOwner" : "user1",
      "using": true
    }
  ]}
}
```

or those 2 object only.

Comment: Any query using that I can get expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is what you are looking for.

You can use it in an `[aggregate][1]`

- with `$match` you select the documents you want in the collection
- Add then with `$filter` you filter the list

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "pcID": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      pc: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$pc",
          as: "pc",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$pc.pcName",
              "Dell"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/07ADIErfiZ6)

Comment: When I'm changing value from "Dell" to "Lenovo" it is giving blank array.

Comment: Oh yes. I used $gt instead of $eq ... I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Aggregate

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "user",
      "pc.pcName": "Dell"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "number": 1,
      "pc": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$pc",
          "as": "pc",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$pc.pcName",
              "Dell"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Can you explain projection part?

Comment: Yeah sure. We are basically projection all the fields that we require in the result. `name: 1, number: 1` tells the projection to include theses fields in the result. Since we only need the selected objects from the `pc` array we are using the `$filter` operator that will tell the database which objects inside the `pc` array we need to project